# Units that contain special characters in SIunitx

Tags: siunitx, units

What is the proper way to typeset an entity of number plus unit if the unit contains characters such as '.' or '-' ?

Of course I could just type like `16\,Std.` or `5\,Mol-\%` but for consistency I put all entities of number+unit in `\SI{}{}`.
For dots I found that putting it in brackets works `\SI{16}{{Std.}}`. But for hyphens it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Fünf Gramm Uranhexafluorid (\SI{1.0}{eq.}) und \SI{100}{mg} Katalysator (\SI{5}{Mol-\%} wurden hinzugefügt. Das Gemisch wurde dann für \SI{16}{Std.} gerührt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this but I think you should use `\DeclareSIUnit{\molproz}{Mol-\percent}` and `\SI{5}{\molproz}` etc. Similar for `Std.` and `eq.` By the way, why are you using `\SI{100}{mg}` instead of `\SI{100}{\milli\gram}`?

Comment: Or `\num{16}` Std. if there should be unusual abbreviations of units...

Answer (score 4):

With the standard settings, the font used to print units is the math mode one; this means that `-` will be interpreted as a minus. As detailed in the documentation, one may use `\text` to ensure text mode is always used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{10}{Mol\text{-}\%}

\end{document}
```